# How to resolve this paradox involving Cantor's diagonal argument?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, infinity, paradoxes

Let's define the elements of a countable infinite set of numbers as follows:

$$s_1 = 0.0000000...$$
$$s_2 = 0.1000000...$$
$$s_3 = 0.1100000...$$
$$s_4 = 0.1110000...$$
$$s_5 = 0.1111000...$$
$$...$$

Using Cantor's diagonal argument, it should be possible to construct a number outside this set by choosing for each digit of the decimal expansion a digit that differs from the underlined digits below (a "diagonal"):

$$s_1 = 0.\underline{0}000000...$$
$$s_2 = 0.1\underline{0}00000...$$
$$s_3 = 0.11\underline{0}0000...$$
$$s_4 = 0.111\underline{0}000...$$
$$s_5 = 0.1111\underline{0}00...$$
$$...$$

The choice of a particular number for these digits should be arbitrary, as long as they are different than the underlined digit at each step. As all numbers of the diagonal are 0, let's choose 1 for all of them. Thus, Cantor's diagonal argument produces this number, that in theory should be outside this set:

$$C = 0.111111..$$

The paradox is that this number looks very much like it is inside the set! In fact, no matter how far you go down the sequence, the partial Cantor diagonal number that you are constructing up to that point corresponds to exactly the next member of the set!

How can you solve this paradox?

Comment: There is no paradox, all elements of the list have finitely many $1$s in their expansion, while the new number doesn't, so it can't be equal to any of those in the list

Comment: This number is not in the set. Take a specific $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it will have only $n$ number of $1$s, not infinitely many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not in the set. Your set is$$\left\{\frac1{10},\frac{11}{100},\frac{111}{1\,000},\cdots\right\}$$and the number that you get is $\frac19$, which does *not* belong to it.

Comment: Forestalling a possible confusion on the OP's part: **not all sets are closed**. Just because $1\over 9$ is "almost in" this set doesn't meant that $1\over 9$ is *actually in* the set.